What is the maximum dBu I can send into a microphone input in this schematic?
The schematic below is from the Icom 9700 radio service manual (page 80).  I would like to feed this input from a mixer board's ALT-3/4 outputs, and I want to avoid blowing the TS462 microphone preamp on the radio. Thus, we need to figure out if attenuation is necessary. I think the ALT-3/4's are line-outs which are spec'ed with a max output of 22dBu (~9.7V RMS).
Schematic info:

The red line is +8V
"R2127" is fed with +5V (I think, the net is labeled DA5V, so educated guess).
The MICI net is the (unbalanced?) input from the "microphone" (ehem, mixer board).

The simplified schematic does not indicate the TS462's Vcc, but the TS462 datasheet says operating supply voltage of 2.7-10V (so probably +8V), and Vid is +/- Vcc.
Question: Is 22dBu (9.7V RMS) of audio safe to send into this circuit without causing damage? If not, how much attenuation is needed?
I've really never used an opamp or worked with audio signals in detail, so your feedback is appreciated! Click to zoom:


The op-amp is powered from 5V and has rail-to-rail output, guaranteed to be 4Vpp. We can assume ideal 5Vpp for simplicity.
It is an inverting configuration, with gain of 20.6, which means the op-amp stops working propery well below 0.242 Vpp, or 0.086 Vrms.
The fact that the reference voltage is not exactly half Vcc but 2.368V means that the input range is less due to the asymmetry. And the op-amp guarantees the output is in the range of 0.5 to 4.5V for 4Vpp output.
This limits the input to 0.194 Vpp or 0.069 Vrms.
As the op-amp output is almost divided by half to an ADC which takes 3Vpp, the ADC input is not a limiting factor.
This is consistent with the fact that the radio is calibrated with 30 mVrms signal on the mic input.
So it does not make any sense to feed in more than 69 mVrms.
Even if the signal clips, the op-amp tolerates at least 5Vpp signal when it is powered but as the signal must be within 0V and 5V at op-amp inputs. The diodes start conducting when voltage differs about 0.5V from the reference bias, but the bias is also very weak and can't clamp much current.
So it does not make much sense to feed in even 1 Vrms even if it does not damage anything.
Feeding in external audio needs to be attenuated down to sensible mic levels, and with AC coupling cap due to the 8V bias supply.
It may be a good idea to simulate mic DC current with a DC pull-down resistor from MIC to GND, as it will discharge the AC coupling capacitor too whem radio is powered off.
So 69 mVrms is -22 dBu or -23 dbV.
The 30mVrms calibration voltage used is -28 dBu or -30dBV.
The 1k input bias resistor is 0.1W RMS, so it allows 10 VRMS around 8V bias.
The specs indicate 10mA mic current max, it must be taken as peak value as nothing else is given. It ends up being 7 VRMS.
22dBu (9.7V RMS) is 27 Vpp, I would not recommend sending this to MIC input as it is absurdly high and may damage something.

I was hoping the OP would work out the numbers for himself.

@AnalogKid There might have been other limits than the one imposed by op-amp supply and gain. The ADC could have been a problem. Plus, I am not sure if the question was about limit of damage, limit of clipping, or typical input. For example, in broadcast studio, you typically leave in a factor of 8x or 10x for peak transients from the nominal level. The level output by the mic itself is unknown, but with gain of just 20x, it may not be directly an electret capsule, but may contain an amplifer.

Thanks for helping me with the math!  I wouldn't have gotten there on my own.  So it looks like I need to attenuate down to -28dBu from 22dBu (att 50dBu), so maybe start at 60dB and turn it up if needed?  What do you think?

follow-up question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/719238/256265

The circuit has external input overvoltage clipping diodes, but we need to see more of the schematic to evaluate them in this circuit.  Here is something to consider . . .
The opamp circuit is configured for an inverting gain of 20.  As a first-order approximation:
Determine the voltage rails for the opamp.
Then go to the datasheet and see what the output voltage swing range is with those rails.
Then divide that by 20.  The result is the peak-to-peak input signal amplitude that initiates clipping in the opamp output stage.
